# Comment décide-t-on du genre des néologismes en français? (How is the gender of new words decided in French?)

Tags: genre, néologismes, noms

Les francophones inventent sans cesse de nouveaux noms, mais il faut décider à chaque fois quel sera le genre du nom.

Récemment, le français a assimilé des mots comme "Internet" et "googol". J'ai remarqué que l'on a accepté que ces deux noms soient masculins. Parfois un néologisme vient d'un mot français qui existe déjà, et son genre en est sans doute détérminé (est-ce que quelqu'un aurait des exemples de ce phénomène?), mais qu'est-ce qui se passe quand un nouveau mot n'est pas dérivé d'un mot français? Son genre est-il masculin par défaut? Qui est-ce qui décide; est-ce que l'Académie française a le dernier mot?

---

New nouns are coming to be used by French speakers all the time, but one thing that must be decided is what the gender of the noun is to be.

Recently, words like "Internet" and "un googol" have entered French.  I've noticed that both of these are accepted as masculine.  Sometimes a new word is derived from an existing French word and presumably the existing word's gender determines the new word's gender (anyone have any examples of this?), but what about when a new word is not derived from an existing French word?  Does the gender just default to masculine?  Who decides this; does l'Académie française have the final say?

Comment: quelle bonne question. j'ai la même question ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Je pense que le genre des nouveaux mots s'impose par la pratique. Ces nouveaux mots n'entrent dans le dictionnaire qu'une fois qu'ils sont déjà utilisés par une bonne partie de la population, et à ce moment là, le genre est déjà établi (de façon empirique souvent).

Cependant, je crois que les nouveaux mots ont tendance à hériter du genre du concept dont ils dérivent. Ainsi, on parle du « réseau Internet » et il est donc logique que le mot « Internet » soit masculin. De même, un mobile est un téléphone.

Pour ce qui est des mots féminins, je viens de découvrir « [mémorette](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9morette) », qui dérive de « mémoire » et est donc féminin.

Comment: Et c'est quoi, une mémorette? Un pense-bête?

Comment: Une clé USB visiblement : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9morette

Comment: Urrrgggh. (Merci, je pensais que c'était pour _post-it_... 2007? Bigre!)

Comment: Mémorette? Je n'avais jamais vu le mot, serait-il par hasard plus courant au Québec?

Answer (score 17):

En plus de l'usage établi et de l'utilistion du genre des racines du mot, il faut noter un moyen de déterminer le genre qui est **par le suffixe du mot** lui-même. Prenons l'exemple des mots familiers utilisés (au moins dans mon entourage) pour désigner une *télécommande* (qui a lui-même pris le genre de *commande*). Certains peuvent dire *zapette*, féminin par son suffixe en *-ette*; d'autres *zapeur*, masculin par son suffix en *-eur*. Quant au genre de *ordinateur* et *calculatrice*, ils sont imposés par le suffixe, mais rien n'aurait interdit d'avoir un *calculateur* (ce qui s'utilise d'ailleurs pour les super-calculateurs, les ordinateurs très haute performance) ou une *ordinatrice* (qui n'existe pas, sauf pour des significations religieuses).

Comment: Pour moi un calculateur, c’est autre chose. C’est qqn qui joue stratégiquement :)

Comment: Alors, "calculateur" est donc polysémique :-)

Answer (score -1):

Grammarians looked for many rules to attribute a gender to a name, but in facts a word get its gender when they are spoken in a sentence.

Sometimes, it never gets in the dictionary. For example *autoroute* is feminine in Swizterland. However, the dictionary attributes a feminine gender, most person around me uses “*un autoroute*”. s/he will systematically use one gender in the discourse. If the gender switches, for example to adapt to an audience, the switch is immediate and definitive, without hesitations, and often without the speaker being conscious of the switch.

The same is true for the long lasting case like *amour*, *délices*, *orgue* masculine when singular and feminine when plural. As well as true bigenders *après-midi*, interligne*, *oeuvre* or false homonyms: *bulbe*, *cartouche*, *claque*, *faune*, *manche*, *mémoire*, *mode*, *poste*, *solde*…

Comment: I never heard *autoroute* with the masculine gender. Also, I doubt your first claim makes sense, could you back it up with references? The rest of this answer is not related with neologisms, as far as I can tell, is it?

Comment: Possibly in radio records of the 70's. I've only heard "un autoroute" up to the age of 15.