# Genre des mots étrangers insérés dans du français

Tags: genre, informatique

> **Pas vraiment un duplicata, mais lié tout de même :**
>   [Comment décide-t-on du genre des néologismes en français? (How is the gender of new words decided in French?)](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/322/comment-decide-t-on-du-genre-des-neologismes-en-francais-how-is-the-gender-of)

En parcourant quelques pages de documentation informatique en français, je tombe sur un mot technique en anglais, `query` (= requête), qui désigne un mot clé d'un langage de programmation. L'auteur parle d'*une `query`*, ce qui sonne faux dans ma tête, ayant toujours parlé d'*un `query`*.

Au vu du nombre de mots techniques que je croise dans ce domaine, je me pose la question : comment décider si un mot est masculin ou féminin en français alors que le mot est anglais et ne doit pas être traduit. On ne pourrait pas dire « boucler avec un `tant-que` » au lieu de « boucler avec un `while` », ça n'aurait pas de sens.

---

**Note :**  Les termes écrits en `code` sont bien des codes et non des *anglicismes*. Ma question n'a aucun rapport avec des mots devenus français par emprunt à une langue étrangère, elle porte sur le genre des **commandes informatiques** en tant que telles.

Comment: Je dirais, sans en avoir une preuve formelle, que le genre est celui de la traduction en français, et le masculin si cette traduction n'existe pas. Et je n'ai jamais dit *un query* :)

Comment: Je ne vois pas en quoi ce n'est pas un doublon, que ce soit dans le cadre d'un jargon ou pour des néologismes d'usage plus large, le genre de nouveaux mots se détermine de la même manière: par l'usage influencé par les finales, les locutions sous-entendues, les mots proches, et le fait que le masculin a tendance à l'emporter.  (Personnellement, si j'avais à donner un genre à _query_, je crois que ce serait aussi féminin à cause du genre de _requête_ justement.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comment décide-t-on du genre des néologismes en français? (How is the gender of new words decided in French?)](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/322/comment-decide-t-on-du-genre-des-neologismes-en-francais-how-is-the-gender-of)

Comment: Perso, moi j'ai souvent vu des professeurs écrire du pseudo-code avec des boucles "tant que"/"pour" ... (Mais c'est vraiment bizarre)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En écrivant « un `query` » ou « une `query` », je pense que l'on réalise une **métonymie**, figure de style consistant à désigner un objet ou une idée par un autre terme. Du coup, le genre dépend du mot que l'on sous-entend. Si tu parles d'un **mot-clé**, tu diras le `query` bien qu'il soit préférable de dire « le mot-clé `query` ». Tu noteras par ailleurs l'utilisation d'un *article défini*. Dire un query n'a pas de sens car cela signifie que le mot-clé n'est pas quelque chose de défini ce qui serait paradoxal.

Si par contre tu désignes la requête et non plus le mot-clé utilisé en programmation, il faudra bien sûr dire « une (ou la) requête » et non « (une ou la) query », cela va de soi.

Answer (score 1):

*Un query* ? Je n'avais jamais entendu cet anglicisme dans la mesure où le terme français est extrêmement utilisé et absolument clair. (comme tu le précisais déjà)

> Une requête.

Quand il n'y a pas d'équivalent français réellement utilisé, je comprends très aisément qu'on veuille employer le terme anglais, nous le faisons tous dans le contexte du langage professionnel en informatique, mais là... ! Tu dis aussi « j'ai installé une *mouse* sur mon *computer* » ?

Comment: Outre le fait que la question est plus large que simplement le terme _query_, je veux signaler que cette utilisation ne m'étonne guère. Ici nous jargonnons beaucoup et notre jargon a beaucoup de mots directement empruntés à l'anglais (domaine technique et société américaine obligent) et certains ont des emprunts qui me surprennent, l'usage français ayant des équivalents très bien établis (p.e. j'ai vu utiliser _user_ pour utilisateur).

Comment: Ouh là ! On s'est mal compris. Je parlais de la commande `query`, en tant qu'élément de programmation. Il est bien clair que dans une conversation, j'utiliserais le mot requête, mais là, je parlais du mot-clé `query`, pas de l'action de faire une requête.

Answer (score 0):

Certains décident en fonction de leur expérience en tant qu'expat ! Quand on se rencontre, au café, ou à l'Alliance Française de notre pays d'accueil, on se fait parfois se genre de remarque :

> Ah bon, toi tu dis **le** *bidule* ? C'est marrant parce que moi je dis **la** *bidule*.

C'est d'ailleurs intéressant comme la communauté des Français à l'étranger a une influence sur l'importation, le produit « fini » en quelque sorte, d'un anglicisme à venir. Je me suis d'ailleurs toujours demandé si un nouvel anglicisme entrera sur le « marché » du vocabulaire français dès lors qu'un ex-expat avec pignon sur rue (éditeur, journaliste, blogger) rentrera en France...