# Comment peut-on spécifier le genre d'un nom d'une langue étrangère?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, anglais, genre

Souvent on utilise des noms qui viennent d'une langue étrangère, surtout celle de l'anglais ainsi que `framework` ou `template`, est-ce qu'on est obligé de connaitre le genre de ces mots dans la langue d'origine ou bien on dit tout simplement `le template` en utilisant le genre masculin?

Comment: Voir ici https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/322 ou ici https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6282, par exemple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il est évident que si le mot étranger se trouve dans un dictionnaire français alors... ta question ne se pose pas.

Si ce n'est pas le cas ET que tu souhaites à tout prix l'utiliser c'est que... tu fais comme tu veux alors... tu choisiras le genre... comme tu veux.

En général (il y a des exceptions, particulièrement en dehors de l'hexagone) on gardera le genre tel que déterminé dans la langue d'origine en rapportant le neutre au masculin.

*template* et *framework* sont du neutre en anglais -> masculin si importés.

---

<sub>Noter que [ce site](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme) suggère des équivalents français à de très nombreux termes étrangers.</sub>

---

<sub>Noter aussi la remarque sur le genre sémantique faite par 
Luke Sawczak. Avec la restriction que, dans ces cas, l'équivalent français existe et que ma préférence serait à l'utiliser.</sub>

---

<sub>Un commentaire en marge évoque des différences de choix dans certains cas.</sub>
<sub>Dans les deux cas cités par l'OP et ceux qui vont avec appartenant à un jargon technique, en cas de reprise, *en français dans le texte* on parle de **calque**. Dans les cas cités en commentaires on parle d' **emprunt**.

La justification du genre (et du nombre) dans les cas d' **emprunts** est par plus complexe, certains allant même dans leurs explications jusqu'à chercher des critères sociologiques voire psychologiques.</sub>

Comment: Aurais-tu une référence pour « on gardera le genre tel que déterminé dans la langue d'origine », à quelles langues cela s'applique-t-il ?

Comment: Je me fais l'avocat du diable et indique que ces emprunts, s'ils sont entrés dans le vocabulaire autant en Europe (où on leur laissera une chance d'entrer dans les dictionnaires usuels) qu'en Amérique (où on tentera, parfois en vain parfois non, de les anéantir à grands coups de néologismes qui sonnent plus français), il y a une chance non nulle que le genre adopté à l'oral diffère entre les deux rivages de l'Atlantique. Par exemple, *guacamole* (m en Europe, f au Québec), *job* (id.), *vidéo* (f en Europe, initialement m au Québec, mais les vieux comme moi sont désormais minoritaires).

Comment: @Montéedelait : Attention, vous citez là des *emprunts* et... avec les emprunts, c'est une autre histoire. Réponse augmentée.

Comment: Les emprunts furent des termes étrangers avant d'acquérir le statut d'emprunt, et ont vécu dans la langue française avant leur consécration dans un dictionnaire. Vous mentionnez d'ailleurs la présence possible de ces mots étrangers dans les dictionnaires, auquel cas le genre est clair et définitif. Ou bien... l'est-il vraiment???

Comment: @Montéedelait : *clair et définitif* ? Ie genre et le nombre seront aussi *définitivement* fixés que... son orthographe. Ni plus ni moins. On connaît dans le moyen-français quelques cas d'emprunts au latin ayant fluctué. 3 ou 4 sont passés dans le français contemporain sous des genres bien discutables. (entendre qui provoquent un questionnement) On parle là d'*anomalies*. Vous noterez au passage le nombre de plantes / genres d'espèces pour lesquelles nous hésitons tous les jours.

Comment: Et sans même aller dans les noms rares et compliqués, on peut penser à pétale, en effet.

Answer (score 9):

Alors, si on parle « surtout » des mots empruntés à l'anglais, on notera que le concept de genre grammatical n'existe pas vraiment en anglais. Il n'y a donc rien à emprunter ! *

Mais qu'il s'agit de l'anglais ou d'une langue ayant un concept de genre pareil à celui du français, non, ce n'est pas vraiment ce genre qui décide, c'est la logique interne du français. Cette logique se base souvent sur la forme du mot : [Lyster (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0959269506002304) à trouvé qu'à peu près 80 % des mots dans son corpus de 10 000 avaient une terminaison qui permettait à prédire systématiquement le genre (c'est-à-dire qui avait une fiabilité de 90 % ou plus pour tous les mots où elle apparaît).

Bien sûr, la terminaison de l'emprunt ne correspond pas toujours exactement à une terminaison en français. Pour les langues romaines, telles l'espagnol, il est facile de les rapprocher (p.ex. espagnol *-cion*, français *-tion*). Quant aux autres langues, il y a de fausses ressemblances qu'on peut exploiter ; des mots auxquels les locuteurs associeront l'emprunt ; ou le français peut même ajouter une terminaison appropriée, modelée sur des mots connus qui ont une vague similarité. On discute un peu de ces stratégies dans [ce fil-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/322).

S'il est évident que la forme du mot n'est pas française, on utilisera souvent la valeur par défaut, c'est-à-dire le masculin.

Comme la discussion dans les commentaires le montre, il est aussi possible que les diverses variétés de français emploient ces stratégies de différentes façons : pour « deadline » le français de France associe ce deuxième morphème à « ligne » (féminin) tandis qu'au Canada on a suivi la règle qu'étant un mot anglais, il est neutre/masculin. Dans la salle de chat, l'utilisateur Montée de lait a aussi partagé le cas de [un / une job](http://oreilletendue.com/2014/01/28/et-voila-le-travail/).

---

<sup>* Comme indiqué ci-dessous, on peut dire que les pronoms personnels (*he, she* etc.) conservent la distinction grammaticale, et qu'on peut classer certains mots, y compris ceux qui désignent des êtres humains, comme masculin ou féminin et les autres comme neutre (disant *it*). Aussi, certains mots en anglais ont un genre sémantique : *mother*, *father*, *bachelor*, *bride*, etc. Pour ce type de mot — si jamais on devait en emprunter un ... — la langue receptrice fait souvent la même déduction.</sup>

Comment: Je suis un peu surpris. Le *"genre grammatical"* existe bien en anglais puisque c'est cela que certains pronoms réalisent régulièrement. Il est juste le plus souvent : neutre.

Comment: @aCOSwt Les pronoms personnels expriment le genre : la liste des mots où le genre est marqué ne comporte que *he, she* (p. sujet), *him, her* (p. objet), *himself, herself* (p. réflexif), *his, hers* (p. possessif), *his, her* (déterminant). C'est bien fascinant que la distinction est conservée pour ces 10 mots, qui s'emploient seulement pour les êtres vivants et même pas souvent pour les animaux ("There's a tiger! **It's** gonna eat me!"). On pourrait donc dire que des mots comme *mother*, *father*, *bachelor*, *actress* ont un genre avec lequel le pronom est accordé.

Comment: Je te l'accorde bien volontiers (bien que... pour la forme... au RTYC... le *bateau* est aussi du féminin). Cela étant, d'accord avec ce que tu dis mais cela ne fait pas pour autant que le concept de *genre grammatical* n'existe pas en anglais. Il est juste le plus souvent : neutre.

Comment: @aCOSwt Merci pour ce perspectif soutenable. J'ai ajouté une note pour expliquer ça. (Note que même si les bateaux et les nations sont historiquement du genre féminin, de nos jours c'est un usage marqué : le plus souvent on l'exclut, on risque même d'attirer de l'attention négative.)

Comment: Marqué, le féminin des véhicules et trucs à moteur en anglais? Dans le grand Nord canadien, sur les petits camps où je me rends, il est encore très vivant: snowmobile, skidoo, chain-saw, quad, etc. are still commonly feminine. And even an oil stove is sometimes referred to as feminine.

Comment: @Montéedelait Ah, that's interesting! It must be a regional thing. Here in Toronto and area, I think you'd get anywhere from a bemused smile to an odd look if you said "she" for any of those things. It feels like a historical drama on CBC or an impression of a colourful character. How out of touch we are!

Comment: Well, Toronto has a lot of people, and we are but a minor fraction of that population in the 3 territories altogether, including the visitors like me in those regions. Perhaps my vision of *“this way of speaking is alive”* is heavily biased, based on the so few people my sample represents?

Comment: @Montéedelait Whose vision isn't biased? :) It's an interesting conversation — I've followed up in chat.

Comment: J'ai découvert ce matin qu'on disait ***un** deadline* au Canada. De ce côté-ci, j'ai toujours entendu et dit ***une** deadline*, certainement à cause de la proximité entre *line* et *ligne*. À l'inverse, on dit ici *un bullshit* mais c'est *une bullshit* outre-Atlantique...

Comment: @jlliagre En effet, bullshit est féminin ici. On dira par contre le plus souvent *«[c'est] de la bullshit»*, pas *«une bullshit»*.

Comment: Oui, on dit *c'est du bullshit* ici.